# Java: passing a new Class to a Constructor

Tags: java, parameters, constructor, parameter-passing

I'm new to Java and just tried something that worked, but I don't completely understand it.

```
public void test(){
    Employee employee = new Employee(new Date(1,2,1990));
}
```

I'm calling the constructor of Employee and then **passing as a parameter a new Class and calling its constructor. What is this called?** I have not been able to find any information on this, and would like to understand what is actually happening here.

More detail: My first effort was to create an instance of the Date class and then pass the object as the parameter, but to save on code and memory I decided to try this instead. It works as I intended, but I would like to understand the object life cycle of this, and to know if there are any drawbacks to doing it this way?

Thank you @hfontanez! A search for **"anonymous reference"** helped me find some info on this. But there isn't much out there that explains it.

Comment: "What is this called?" It's just calling a constructor.

Comment: There is no special name for that. You are simply calling a constructor that takes one argument. That said, you are passing an anonymous reference of the `Date` object since the instance you are passing doesn't have a (variable) name.

Comment: You call a constructor with another object created by calling `Date`'s constructor as parameter.

Comment: (As a side note, `Date` is obsolete; you should generally use `java.time.LocalDate` instead.)

Comment: Google things like `heap vs stack memory` or `heap vs stack variables` and you'll find some examples of the difference between `creating the object` and the `reference to the created object`.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. And even if you insisted on using `Date`, you should still stay far away from the three-arg constructor. It’s been deprecated for 25 years (roughly) because it works unreliably across time zones. Instead as @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- mentioned use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the constructor of 'Employee' with an instance of 'Date', while creating the instance of date means, that you are calling the constructor of 'Date' with 1,2,1990.

This would do the same (I think that's what you meant):

```
public void test() {
    // Create an instance of 'Date' by passing the arguments '1', '2' and '1990' to the constructor of 'Date'.
    Date date = new Date(1,2,1990);

    // Create an instance of 'Employee' by passing the argument 'date' to the constructor of 'Employee'.
    Employee employee = new Employee(date);
}
```

The only difference between this and your posted code is that you are not storing the created object in your code.

So you can not call it like `date.doAnything`.

Comment: Your example is what I did at first, and then I modified it to reduce code and memory. And I have no further need for an instance of the Date class with that info.

Comment: If you don't need it, your way is the more efficient one.
But is your question now answered?

Answer (score 0):

The only difference is that you do not have a reference to the Date object within the test method so you won't be able to do anything with it in the test method. It seems like you don't need to do anything with it except pass it to the Employee object so there's no reason not to do it. It will not effect the way the Employee object will be able to use it because the Employee object does not know or care whether the Date argument was passed from a variable or anonymously.

Answer (score 0):

Various words are used describe various aspects of your code. Just as you have *instantiation* of an `Employee` object, you also have instantiation of an object of the poorly designed and long outdated `Date` class. What comes out of the instantiation is a reference to the newly created object. In case of `Employee` you are assigning this reference to a variable, thus giving it a name. Since you don’t do that with the `Date` reference, the others are correct in calling it *an anonymous reference*. Some may also talk less formally about *creating the object on the fly*. It is being passed to the `Employee` constructor where it is used to give a value to the parameter of the constructor, so inside the constructor is it no longer anonymous.

### Pros and cons

You said

> … to save on code and memory I decided to try this instead.

It’s good to try different options and see what works, what does not, and what you think most clearly expresses your intentions and is more readable (for other readers, and for yourself when you visit this code again in 6 months after having forgot everything about it). You are hardly saving any memory. The compiler is usually smart enough not to use more memory than necessary no matter how you write your code. My opinion is: Saving code should not be a goal. Your goal is to write clear, readable and maintainable code, not to write little code. Sometimes the two go hand in hand since often reading less code can be easier than reading more code. One clear drawback in your case is exactly that you are not giving the date a name. If you assigned the date to a variable called `birthDate`, you would be telling the reader that this is the employee’s birth date. If the variable instead was called `hireDate`, we again knew. From your code as it stands we are getting no idea what is the relationship between the employee and the date.

### java.time

The modern and recommended version of your code would be

```
Employee employee = new Employee(LocalDate.of(1990, Month.FEBRUARY, 1));
```

`LocalDate.of()` is a *factory method* that creates a new `LocalDate` object. It does so by calling a constructor with `new` somewhere behind the scenes.

Just to underline how confusing the `Date` constructor that you used is, when I ran your code in Asia/Kolkata time zone it created a `Date` of Sat Aug 11 00:00:00 IST 1906. Don’t ask why. Just stop using that constructor and stop using `Date` at all.

**Link:** [Trail: Date Time (The Java™ Tutorials)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I'll look into the java.time class, but for what I'm playing with I actually created my own Date class that just hold 3 integers for month, day, and year.

Comment: Creating your own `Date` class is a very fine exercise, applauding. For production code one would never do it. So in your code `new Date(1,2,1990)` means January 2, 1990?

Answer (score -1):

This code creates a new date object and passes it as a parameter to the constructor of the Employee class. The date object is available for use later.

```
public void test(){
    Date date = new Date(1,2,1990);
    Employee employee = new Employee(Date);
}
```

This code passes an **anonymous reference** to the Date class as a parameter to the constructor of the Employee class. Therefore the date object that is created only exists for the lifetime of the constructor, and cannot be used or referenced later.

```
public void test(){
    Employee employee = new Employee(new Date(1,2,1990));
}
```

Comment: "a date object is not created" what? of course it is created.

Comment: *only exists for the lifetime of the constructor*, better, but it depends on what the constructor does with it. Typically it would assign it to an instance variable where it would live longer than the code creating the instance.